# How can I create an account in a private network?

Tags: private-network

I have a private network with 2 nodes, but when I want to access an account with Horizon, these errors are shown to me:

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/not_found",
  "title": "Resource Missing",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "The resource at the url requested was not found.  This is usually occurs for one of two reasons:  The url requested is not valid, or no data in our database could be found with the parameters provided."
}
node 1:
HTTP_PORT=11626
PEER_PORT=11625
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
RUN_STANDALONE=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test Roya Network ; September 2018"
NODE_SEED="SDASSKSWHEZ5FV4SESYRTMLQUVBXVUQALLNQQUXBAXKEWZMYJSOFWSPC self"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=roya host=localhost user=kuknus password=123456"
NODE_NAMES=[
 "GCVCVH2OTQXNTYZVPDN4YP2GKHXQLCMG45W3D26WFVROA6DZBNOR7MH6 two"
]
KNOWN_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11627"]
PREFERRED_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11627"]


FAILURE_SAFETY=0
CATCHUP_RECENT=60480
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=["$self", "$two"]

[HISTORY.local]
get="cp tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}"

node2 :

my configure files are these:
HTTP_PORT=11628
PEER_PORT=11627
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
RUN_STANDALONE=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test Roya Network ; September 2018"
NODE_SEED="SAFKOGXH6HAF62ZEGN7NHICYNENQI27PZ73GBN6J4D23ZDOSD5622DES self"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=node host=localhost user=kuknus password=123456"
NODE_NAMES=[
 "GDVPXTA7YWNUVMZIXT4VRGUD2ENSGRCH77ZCBXQJGV3RKPUHZUZV74V5 one"
]
KNOWN_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11625"]
PREFERRED_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11625"]


FAILURE_SAFETY=0
CATCHUP_RECENT=60480
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=["$self", "$one"]

[HISTORY.local]
get="cp tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}"

[HISTORY.h1]
get="curl -sf http://one.localhost/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} -o {1}"
```

Comment: How about your Friendbot? Could you confirm it is running fine? (also Horizon - not going to work if it is misconfigured, e.g. unmatched NETWORK_PASSPHRASE)